# WindowLeaked in different Android Versions

Tags: android, dialog, motorola-droid

I have a listview of producers that when you click it opens a Custom Dialog with many options. When you click in one of the options goes to another activity and the Dialog is not closed so if you come back you can choose another option from that producer that you have selected before. The problem is that in the Moto G 2014 with android 4.4.4 it's giving me a WindowLeaked, I've tested in a S3 with Android 4.3 and in a Moto G 2013 with android 4.4.4 and doesn't give me a WindowLeaked, it works as I wanted, with the dialog open so I can do another action. Can some one explain me why?

Here is the LOGCAT:

```
    10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity (DELETED BY ME).AtividadesActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42604ff8 V.E..... R....... 0,0-640,672} that was originally added here
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:359)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at (DELETED BY ME).AtividadesActivity$12.onItemClick(AtividadesActivity.java:648)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-23 09:44:30.587: E/WindowManager(14134):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Why don't you close the dialog in `onPause` and if it was open, re-open the dialog in `onResume`

Comment: That is one solution, but it should work as I'm doing, because it's working in other phones, I'm having problems with the spinner too with this Moto G 2014. Is that normal? I'm kind of new with Android Development.

Comment: It might work on some phones, but it's not an Android pattern to leave dialogs open when you leave an Activity (and expect them to be open when you come back). Selecting an option on a dialog usually means the dialog should close. Perhaps you need to think about the UX. Either way it's not something I'd recommend or class as a "normal" Android pattern - hence the unguaranteed behaviour

Comment: you have to call dialog.dismiss(); in onPause() method of the activity ....

Comment: Ok, I'll do in that way now, thanks.

Comment: The problem why is giving me a windowLeack is because the Activity is been closed in the Moto G 2014 when I open another one. I've tested and the onCreate is been called, but it shouldn't, I'm not closing the activity, I'm only opening a new one with the Intent class. Do you guys know what is happening? Even if I close the Dialog in the onPause and save in a variable if it's was open and try to re-open in the onResume, it won't work because the variable is been reseted because the activity is been closed, and this is happening with ALL my activities in the Moto G 2014 with Android 4.4.4.

Comment: I've found the problem, in the developers option was marked to not keep activities, lol.

Comment: The ActivityManager of the Android OS can close backgrounded  Activities at any time to help free up memory for the foreground activity. @Jonas452 It is a good practice to have that developer option turned on, as this situation can happen in the wild and you need to deal with it